# UWP change DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator etc

Tags: .net, uwp, cultureinfo

In the "normal" .NET you can change the DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator, but this property isn't public anymore (and DateTimeFormatInfo is sealed) in the UWP variant. Some other properties are also inaccessable.

How to create a DateTimeFormatInfo with formatting the way I want? My goal is to have a "what-our-project-considers-invariant" CultureInfo, with "-" as DateSeparator and all dates in the format "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd", instead of the "invariant" date formats that start with the month.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just explicitly format/parse the value with a specific (custom) pattern each time, rather than change `DateTimeFormatInfo` and use a "standard" one.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, That seems to be the only solution then, but it is not as trivial as it sounds, because we also use it for our "invariant" formatting method (and others), which essentially does String.Format(_InvariantCulture, format, args), which we must now modify to inspect all items in the object array to see if it is a DateTime(Offset)...

Comment: To be honest, that's the consequence of using an odd way of performing custom formatting :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, [DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) is not available in UWP apps. In UWP apps, for formatting a date or time, we usually use  [**DateTimeFormatter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206828) class. With this class, we can format the date or time according to user's **Time & Language Seetting**.

If you want to use format "yyyy-MM-dd", you can set the formatter like:

```
var datefmt = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("{year.full}-{month.integer(2)}-{day.integer(2)}");

var dateString = datefmt.Format(DateTime.Now);
```

Also you can use [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For more info, please see [Format dates and times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/use-patterns-to-format-dates-and-times) and [Date and time formatting sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DateTimeFormatting) on GitHub.

Comment: Although this won't solve the String.Format problem, this probably is the WinRT way to go, so therefor I marked it as the solution